# Redirect other page then Home page after login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have created a small windows application for login a web application called ebridge. Its our company's internal website. I have written this code in my button click event to login this site:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://app.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/Default.aspx?user=Ebridge&password=test&filecabinet=E Group"); 

        }
```

Its login successfully. but my issue is that I need to redirect some other page i.e. (**https://s2.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/retrieve/retrieve.aspx**) not home.aspx page after login. Have u any idea or code to overcome this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using Process to redirect?

Comment: @Dinesh: Use Server.Redirect([url]) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (and probably the only way) is to add some logic/code to the page (https://app.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/Default.aspx) itself.

i.e.

from winform

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://app.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/Default.aspx?user=Ebridge&password=test&filecabinet=E Group&redirect=true");
```

notice i have added `redirect=true` at the end of the querystring.

on the default.aspx `Page_Load`

```
string redirect= Request.QueryString["redirect"];
```

`string redirect` will act as a flag. if it's true, and if the login is successful. page will redirect to destined URL.

sample code for (default.aspx):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string redirect= Request.QueryString["redirect"];
            string user= Request.QueryString["user"];
            string password= Request.QueryString["password"];

            if (authorizeUserAndReturnStatus(user,password)&&redirect=="true")  //assuming authorizing return bool, indicating the status of login (true or false) 
               {
                  Response.Redirect("https://s2.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/retrieve/retrieve.aspx");
               }
        }
```

Comment: what is this method "authorizeUserAndReturnStatus(user, password). I could'nt understand it. please explain about it and I have change Process.Start to Response.Redirect(). It redirect to home page but I need to redirect it retrieve.aspx form. how can it possible. Please help about this.

Comment: @Dinesh `authorizeUserAndReturnStatus` just a name for a method. The snippet I've posted had one intention -  to demonstrate the idea. The problem that you are experiencing can't be solved from windows application (unless you write a [web page scraper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)). The only way I see it solved is -  you have to modify the web page itself. you will supply username, password, ... and redirect flag from your windows application. the asp.net page will do all the work. (authorize user and if necessary redirect  to the other page)

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I will try this idea and come back to you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the `Login` control, but something else, why not a simple Response.Redirect?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("https://app.ebridge-solutions.com/ebridge/3.0/Default.aspx?user=Ebridge&password=test&filecabinet=E Group"); 
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is for a Webform (ASP.NET).

Comment: you are assuming its a webform, however OP posted `I have created a small windows application`...

Comment: True, he did - but he also has a tag for ASP.NET.

Comment: yes he did... but I'm quite sure code snippet ,event handling of ` button1_Click` belongs to wiforms. thus OP is not able to `Response.Redirect()`.

Comment: Hi experts I tried this it successfully redirect the home page of ebridge but not there actual page (retrieve.aspx). what I do now? please help.